# What do you call this design that has low poly shapes, but instead of shapes, it's wires

Tags: style-identification

I guess you know very well that be able to search for references you need to exactly know what is what, or what it is called or at least keywords that are related to a subject.

Here is the image:

[image]

I remember seeing a google (a google product / or service) site that incorporate this kind of style, but with "moving wires" using javascript and svg, look, I've tried searching for weeks now, with different keywords, like wires, and low poly lines, but with no luck. Hope you can help me guys out :D

Answer (score 4):

Triangulation, like Delaunay triangulation is a form of tessellation.

Like this: http://kaizouman.github.io/js-delaunay-effect/

Answer (score 0):

This is also called Low Poly and is probably the next trend in graphic design after "flat".

You can Google **low poly** or for a sample you can go here http://www.designyourway.net/drb/an-interesting-trend-low-poly-designs/